# Dijkstra or TSP

Tags: routes, dijkstra

I am developing a web app to show a map and a route between some points. I want to know the short route between that points.

Now I am using the [dijkstra algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) but I was asked to use [TSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) instead.

I want that first and last point would be the same, using dijkstra I have to set the last point to be the same but with TSP it is set automatically.

Are both the same algorithm? just with that modification or are different algorithms?

Any webpage where I can check the pseudo code of TSP?

Comment: Why not look up the definitions + examples on wikipedia? dijkstra calculates the shortest distance from A to B => the distance and used nodes is the result. But TSP calculates the shortest route for a set of points A, B, C, ... => the exact order of those points is the result (distance between them can be calculated with dijkstra)

Answer (score 5):

Travelling Salesman Problem as the name suggests, talks about the shortest route and it's cost starting from a single node and returning to it by ***visiting ALL the other nodes in between***

But Dijkstra is more simple. It just talks about the shortest route and cost between 2 nodes.
So in your case, if there's a need to include all nodes in between then the suggestion for TSP is valid.

P.S. If you want to have  the shortest routes and cost between all pairs of nodes, then you should go for Floyd's algorithm which is basically an extension of Dijkstra.

Comment: or use A* if speed is more critical than accuracy